# Accessing Json objects in perl and reuse it in another JSON

Tags: json, perl, mason

I have received arguments in my mason handler which looks in the following format:

```
$data = {
    'cacheParams' => 0,
    'requests' => {
        'locationId' => 1,
        'uniqueId' => [
            'ABC',
            'DEF',
            'XYZ'
        ]
    }
};
```

I am able to access the requests by using `$data['requests']`. How do I access the values stored in requests, i.e. locationId and uniqueId ? I need to use these values to form another JSON in the following way:

```
my $input = {
    stateID => 44,
    locationId => requests.locationId,
    uniqueId => requests.uniqueId
    .
    .
    .

}
```

Comment: > I am able to access the requests by using $data['requests'].
 Did you mean `$data{'requests'}` instead of `$data['requests']`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$data['requests']` object should be an hash in your way. So you can access to the keys like in the following:

```
$data['requests']->{'locationId'}
$data['requests']->{'uniqueId'}

or 

$requests = $data['requests']
$locationId = $requests->{'locationId'}
$uniqueId = $requests->{'uniqueId'}
```